# Get specific value from `netstat` command in windows

Tags: powershell, port

when i run command `netstat -ano` I have:

```
PS Y:\PowerShell> netstat -ano

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       376
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2222           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2364
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1748
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2556
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3772
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

But what I really wanna get is:

Active Connections

```
   PID
   4
   376
   4
   2364
   1748
   4
   2556
   3772
   4
```

I can't use: `netstat -ano| select PID` because it's not powershell command.

Comment: `netstat -ano | Select -Skip 4 | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames "_", "Proto", "Local Address", "Foreign Address", "State", "PID" | Select PID`. [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) is a clever cookie.

Comment: @JeroenMostert tks, but how to import the ConvertFrom-String?

Comment: `ConvertFrom-String` is a built-in of PowerShell 3.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm currently using PS4, And it tells me that it's not a cmdlet ==!

Comment: My bad -- it's part of PowerShell 5, no earlier version. If your platform supports PowerShell 4, upgrading to 5 is definitely worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell version of netstat is Get-NetTCPConnection and it will return with objects.

```
 Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen
```

Comment: Reluctant upvote. As much as I like `ConvertFrom-String`, nothing beats a native cmdlet.

Comment: `(Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen).OwningProcess`, with the caution that `netstat -ano` returns more than just listening TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the command below to list only PIDs:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OwningProcess
```